# The page isn’t redirecting properly when entering double quotes in the query

Tags: .htaccess

i have a small search function built on to a opencart site. But the problem is that when enter a double quote in the search query it give me a "**The page isn’t redirecting properly**" error and the page doesnt load.

For an example when i search **12pcs book pack red color (15 books)** it works but when i search  **12pcs book pack "red color" (15 books)** it doesnt redirect properly and the url converts to below

```
search=12pcs%book%20pack%20%26amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bquot%3Bred%20color%26amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bquot%3B%20%2820%15count%29
```

on my htaccess i have the below codes

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (Go-http-client) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=401,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&amp;(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1&%2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may try these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Go-http-client [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=401,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]+)&amp;(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1&%2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you sir for posting answer. I understood the rules but having one doubt, is it only sequence of rules causing them not to work sir?

Comment: Sequence and use of `NE` flags both

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for the answer but it doesnt work.. Now the links with `&` are not working.. it redirects like this `%26amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Butm_campaign%3Dgoogle_shopping%26amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Butm_source%3Dgoogle_shopping%26amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Butm_medium%3Dgoogle`

Comment: What is your original URL that you are using for testing?